# Automatic adjustment of a field in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl, create-table, nvarchar

Hello I'm trying to create a table under Oracle 18.1 (SQL Dev).

But I have an error "ORA-00906: missing right parenthesis"

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_TAB (
ID Number PRIMARY KEY,
TEST nvarchar2,
TEST_2 nvarchar,
DATE DATE not null 
);
```

How to create a field without specifying the size of it in nvarchar (or nvarchar2) on Oracle? (I want the field size to adjust automatically)

Thank you

Comment: Not possible. You can't use `nvarchar` (or `varchar` for that matter) without a length restriction. If you need an "unlimited" character column use `CLOB`

Comment: What you mean by *adjust automatically*? You only define the maximum length of a VarChar, but the actual size is *adjusted automatically*.

Comment: ... that's what the 'v' in `varchar` or `nvarchar` means - [***V***ariable-length character string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6__BABCGCHG). You specify the *maximum* size. (Also are you sure you really want `nvarchar2`? In most cases `varchar2` is suitable.)

Comment: besides, `DATE` can not be a column name(reserved keyword). Use `"date"`, `"DATE"` or `DATE_` etc.

Comment: Ok, and if I specify a length of 5, will it truncate my content ?

Comment: No, your content will not be truncated but you will get error if the length exceeds 5.

Comment: By the way, tables have **columns**, not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems. One, you *must* specify a maximum number of characters for a `VARCHAR2` or `NVARCHAR2` column. If you have data that will exceed 4000 bytes (not characters), then just use a `CLOB`.  Second, there is no `NVARCHAR` data type. Third, you cannot create a column named "date," since that's a reserved word. What you want is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_TAB (
    id        number PRIMARY KEY,
    test      nvarchar2(30),
    test_2    nvarchar2(30),
    the_date  date not null 
);
```

Personally, I would use a `NUMBER(10)` for your id, but that's a minor quibble.

You might want to read up on the [NCHAR and NVARCHAR data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1825).